# Building a List from a text file in python

Tags: python

I am a python newbie.

I want to read a text file which reads something like this

```
1345..
245..
..456
```

and store it in a list of lists of integers. I want to keep the numbers and replaces the periods by 0s.How do i do it?

EDIT:
Apologize for the ambiguous output spec

p.s I want the output to be a list of list

```
[ [1,3,4,5,0,0],
[2,4,5,0,0],
[0,0,4,5,6]]
```

Comment: I think just `[0, 0, 4, 5, 6]` for the last one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('yourfile') as f:
    lst = [ map(int,x.replace('.','0')) for x in f ]
```

Which is the same thing as the following nested list-comp:

```
lst = [ [int(val) for val in line.replace('.','0')] for line in f]
```

Here I used `str.replace` to change the `'.'` to `'0'` before converting to an integer.

Comment: as OP wants list of list : `[ [int(x.replace('.','0'))] for x in f ]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- I'm not exactly sure that the OP means by "and store it in a list of lists as integers" ...

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(file) as f:
   lis=[[int(y) for y in x.replace('.','0').strip()] for x in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer in the form of classic for loops, which is easier for a newbie to understand:

```
a_list = []
l = []
with open('a') as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line.rstrip('\n').replace('.', '0'):
            l.append(int(c))
        a_list.append(l)
        #next line
        l = []
print a_list
```