# Make a list of list with string in a text file in Python 3

Tags: python, list

I've a text.txt looking like that :

```
login1 fname1 lname1 mail1\n 
login2 fname2 lname2 mail2\n 
login3 fname3 lname3 mail3\n 
login4 fname4 lname4 mail4\n 
...
```

My goal is to create a list of each line to a list of all line, like that :

```
lst = [[login1, fname1, lname1, mail1],[login2, fname2, lname2, mail2],...]
```

I've make a script who make a list of each line, but I can't make a list inside the line... (I hope you understand...)

I've seen this link [building-a-list-from-a-text-file-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577118/building-a-list-from-a-text-file-in-python) but it's for number and I've fail to reproduc for string.

Here is my beginnig script :

```
file = "export_user.txt"
if os.path.exists(file):
    file = open("export_user.txt", "r") #.readlines()
    list_name = []
    i = 0
    for line in file:
        list_name.append(line)
        list_name[i] = list_name[i].strip()
        i += 1
        print(list_name)

    # with open(file) as f:
        # lst = [map(str(), str()) for line in f]
        # print (lst[0])
```

Comment: why are you adding `1` to i?

Comment: When you do `list_name.append(line)`, you probably want to first split line up into it's components (e.g. with `line_parts = line.split()`), and then append `line_parts` to `list_name`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I increment i to remove for each list the `\n`

Comment: is `login1, fname1, lname1, mail1` a whole string or list elements?

Comment: @AvinashRaj a whole strin, wich I want to transform on a list elements for each lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
with open("file", "r") as f:
    m = f.readlines()
    print [i.strip().split() for i in m]
```

**Output:**

```
[['login1', 'fname1', 'lname1', 'mail1'], ['login2', 'fname2', 'lname2', 'mail2'], ['login3', 'fname3', 'lname3', 'mail3'], ['login4', 'fname4', 'lname4', 'mail4']]
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's not so far, but instead of separate each element by `,` I want a list

Comment: just an intermediate variable to hold the list element for each iteration.

Comment: Ok that's work with `l = [i.strip().split() for i in m]` `print(l)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a="""login1 fname1 lname1 mail1 
login2 fname2 lname2 mail2 
login3 fname3 lname3 mail3 
login4 fname4 lname4 mail4"""

l = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in a.strip().split("\n")]

[['login1', 'fname1', 'lname1', 'mail1'],
 ['login2', 'fname2', 'lname2', 'mail2'],
 ['login3', 'fname3', 'lname3', 'mail3'],
 ['login4', 'fname4', 'lname4', 'mail4']]
```